# How do I create a custom haar classifier?

Tags: opencv

I am struggling to create a custom haar classifier.  I have found a couple tutorials on the web, but they do not specify which version of opencv they are using.  What I need is a very concise and simplified example of the steps that are required, along with a simple dataset of images.  I also need to know the opencv version and the OS platform so I can get it running.  I have tried a matrix of opencv versions on both windows and linux and I have run into memory error after memory error.  I would like to start with a known good set of data and simple commands before expanding it to fit my problem.

Thanks for your help,
Chris

Comment: By Haar Classifier, you mean Boosting + Haar Wavelet like the face detection sample in OpenCV?

Comment: Maybe I know even less about this than I thought, my objective is to get OpenCV to detect the presence of objects that I specify.  I assumed they way to do this would be to create a classifier with my object.  Am I way off base?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OpenCV provides two utility commands `createsamples.exe` and `haartraining.exe`, which can generate xml files used by Haar Classifiers. That is, with the xml file outputted from `haartraining.exe`, you can directly use the face detection sample with your xml file to detect any customized objects.

About the detailed procedures to use the commands, you may consult Page 513-516 in the book *"Learning OpenCV"*, or [this tutorial](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html).

About the internal mechanism of how the classifier works, you may consult the paper **"[Rapid Object Detection using a Boosted Cascade of Simple
Features](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/LBMV07/Papers/viola-cvpr-01.pdf)"**, which has been cited 5500+ times.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that I am on the right track, but I am really wondering if someone could post the commands and args in order and with accompanying images.  That would be helpful!

Comment: Please check the tutorial I provided, whose link is again posted [here](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html). You'll find all the sample images (including positive/negative samples), command usage, and sample command in it. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I did not realize the sample images were included.  My apologies.  I will check that out and report back.

Comment: Good advice, grapeot!  I used the info from the book and I was finally able to get it to work.  Thanks!