# how modify haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml?

Tags: opencv

I am new in opencv and I want to work on face detection methods. I have understand that one of the best methods is by haar features. I know some functions in opencv library for detection faces and training.
can any one help me to understand how haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml is made?
and how can I modify this file?

thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The `haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml` is not meant to be modified (You can however if you really understand what you are doing). It is made from a selected dataset.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a custom haar classifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967057/how-do-i-create-a-custom-haar-classifier)

Answer (score 1):

First read this:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html

followed by:

- http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html
- http://opencvuser.blogspot.in/2011/08/creating-haar-cascade-classifier-aka.html
- http://achuwilson.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/create-your-own-haar-classifier-for-detecting-objects-in-opencv/

Start with good training data.

Cheers.